# How to update ,insert and delete the rows in Sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to android development and i have gone through some tutorials and i wrote an application using sqlite Db.

I have couple of issues as mentioned below
1.How to update rows in my DB?
2.Delete the updated rows?
3.How to insert new rows?

//below code is for updating the rows

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i = i + 100) {
    ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_ID, i + 1);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_NAME, "Test");
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_SERIALNUMBER, String.valueOf(i + 1));
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTALL, 10);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTHIGH, i + 1);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTLOW, i + 1);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_RAWDATA, i + 1);
    db.update(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, cValues, DbHandler.COLUMN_ID,new String[]{String.valueOf(i)});
}
db.close();
```

Delete the specific rows - Below code is clearing total the DB instead of specific rows

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i = i + 100) {
    db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, i+"", null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **insert** rows to the table, use ContentValues (just like your update code) and the [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues)) method:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_ID, i + 1);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_NAME, "Test");
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_SERIALNUMBER, String.valueOf(i + 1));
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTALL, 10);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTHIGH, i + 1);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTLOW, i + 1);
    cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_RAWDATA, i + 1);
    db.insert(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, null, cValues);
}
db.close();
```

The above code will insert 3 rows in the table:

```
1 Test 1 10 1 1 1
2 Test 2 10 2 2 2
3 Test 1 10 3 3 3
```

Now, say that you want to **update** the column `COLUMN_COUNTHIGH` to `100` and the column `COLUMN_COUNTLOW` to `0` of the row with `id = 2`, then you use the [`update()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#update(java.lang.String,%2520android.content.ContentValues,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTHIGH, 100);
cValues.put(DbHandler.COLUMN_COUNTLOW, 0);
db.update(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, cValues, DbHandler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(2)});
db.close();
```

So the `update()` method's arguments are: 
the table's name 
the `ContentValues` 
the `WHERE` clause which contains the column names and the placeholders `?` that will decide which row(s) will be updated
and the value(s) of the column(s) which will be set at the place of `?`
If you want to **delete** say the row with `id = 1`, use the [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D)) method:

```
db.delete(DbHandler.TABLE_USERS, DbHandler.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(1)});
```

The arguments are similar as of those of the `update()` method (without the ContentValues).

Answer (score 0):

you can write dao class (Data Access Object) and working with the class
this is simple you just run sql query on db
this [link](https://github.com/alirezat775/downloader/blob/development/downloader/src/main/java/alirezat775/lib/downloader/core/database/DownloaderDao.kt) will be helping you

for example insert

```
        val query = ("insert into " + DownloaderDatabase.TABLE_NAME + " " +
            "(" +
            ColumnModel.URL + "," +
            ColumnModel.FILE_NAME + "," +
            ColumnModel.STATUS + "," +
            ColumnModel.PERCENT + "," +
            ColumnModel.SIZE + "," +
            ColumnModel.TOTAL_SIZE
            + ")" +
            " VALUES(" + "\"" + fileModel.url + "\"" + ","
            + " " + "\"" + fileModel.fileName + "\"" + ","
            + " " + fileModel.status + ","
            + " " + fileModel.percent + ","
            + " " + fileModel.size + ","
            + " " + fileModel.totalSize + ")")
    database.writableDatabase.execSQL(query)
    database.close()
```

for example update

```
  val query = "update " + DownloaderDatabase.TABLE_NAME + " " +
            " set " + ColumnModel.STATUS + " = " + status +
            " , " + ColumnModel.PERCENT + " = " + percent +
            " , " + ColumnModel.SIZE + " = " + size +
            " , " + ColumnModel.TOTAL_SIZE + " = " + totalSize +
            " where " + ColumnModel.URL + " = " + "\"" + url + "\""
    database.writableDatabase.execSQL(query)
    database.close()
```

for example get data

```
        var model: FileModel? = null
    val query =
        "select * from " + DownloaderDatabase.TABLE_NAME + " where " + ColumnModel.URL + " = \"" + url + "\""
    val cursor = database.readableDatabase.rawQuery(query, null)
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        val itemId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.ID))
        val itemUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.URL))
        val itemFileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.FILE_NAME))
        val itemStatus = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.STATUS))
        val itemPercent = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.PERCENT))
        val itemSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.SIZE))
        val itemTotalSize = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ColumnModel.TOTAL_SIZE))
        model = FileModel(itemId, itemUrl, itemFileName, itemStatus, itemPercent, itemSize, itemTotalSize)
    }
    cursor.close()
    database.close()
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is methods to perform update, insert and delete action in SQLite

1. insertData

   ```
   public long insertData() {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

     values.put(KEY_TITLE, "Title");
     values.put(KEY_ACTIVITY_TYPE,"Event Type");
     values.put(KEY_PLACE, "Event place");
     values.put(KEY, "VALUE");
     values.put(KEY_, "VALUE");

     long id = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
     return id;
   }
   ```
2. updateRow

   ```
   public int updateRow(String row_id) {

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

   values.put(KEY_TITLE, "Title");
   values.put(KEY_ACTIVITY_TYPE,"Event Type");
   values.put(KEY_PLACE, "Event place");
   values.put(KEY, "VALUE");
   values.put(KEY_, "VALUE");

   return db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
           new String[]{row_id});
   }
   ```
3. deleteRow

   public int deleteRow(String row_id) {
       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
       return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, WHERE KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{row_id});
   }